# how to put jpanel into a dialog box?

Tags: java, swing

I need create custom dialog and put JPanel into it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Panel inside dialog box**](http://www.coderanch.com/t/345897/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/Panel-inside-dialog-box) should have what you need.

Comment: thanks a lot. And where I can implement what happend with values from components of panel in dialog? That panel will have some jTextFields and listBoxes.

Comment: In the example from the link it seems it is all done in the user's `createPane` method or you can try manually with: `your_dialog.getContentPane().add(whatever)`

Comment: But when I click "OK", i need to get the values from the fields, or say to user that some are invalid.

Comment: I found it, probably it will be in void close(). Thanks.

Comment: Link based answer... links to a forum which is not just a straigt answer to the question...

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need this,

```
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
myPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 450);
myPanel.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
JDialog dialog = jop.createDialog("This is my Dialog");
dialog.setSize(400, 450);
dialog.setContentPane(myPanel);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

I have tested this code, and working fine for me...